# etree xml python how to modify strictness?

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

I'm using etree in Python to parse an XML file, which happens to have a "<" character inside a node, so it is returning an error:

> "the value of attribute blahblah associated with an element type
>   "BLAHBLAH" must not contain the "<" character.

Without getting into a discussion about well formed XML (I have no choice I didnt write the xml), I'm wondering whether there is a way to suppress the errors in etree within Python, so I can continue parsing the XML?

Comment: without getting into a discussion about well formed XML, no way

Answer (score 0):

Because the less than symbol is used to wrap xml elements, `<` is one of the [predefined xml character entities](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml/xml_character_entities.htm). Consider reading in file and replacing the specific offending `<` (avoiding tags) with its entity value: `&lt;` in XML file before parsing with xml.etree:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

oldfile = "Original.xml" 
newfile = "Output.xml"

with open(oldfile, 'r') as otxt: 
    for rline in otxt: 
         if " < somenumber" in rline: 
            rline = rline.replace(" < somenumber", "&lt; somenumber")

         with open(newfile, 'a') as ntxt: 
            ntxt.write(rline)

tree = ET.parse(newfile)
```

Comment: Umm.. isn't that will replace < at the beginning of a tag name as well

Comment: Indeed, I added a `somenumber`. But if OP can narrow down specific area(s) of offending less than symbol, the conditional search can be changed.